# MongoDB. Create/Write to Log file

Tags: mongodb

I need to do few features:

> 1.Setup output informations in log file (for ex: log_file.txt) . Every new 
>        session for MongoDB server should be written to this log file.
>
> 2.Setup a low level of awareness for log file

Can someone help me please with examples?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear what sort of information you are trying to log, but it sounds like this may be a question about MongoDB server behaviour (logging & auditing) rather than a programming question. Database admin questions would be more appropriate to post on [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb). I suggest reposting on DBA (if appropriate) including more specific examples of what you are trying to log as well as clarification on what "low level of awareness" means. Alternatively, if this is a programming question please update with more details.

Comment: @Stennie Okay, thanks you. Sorry for spam